# writeLine R without quotation marks

Tags: r

I used *gsub* to replace the same "string" in several files by rows in a data.frame, i.e for the file 1, I replace "string" by "replacement 1", for the file 2, "string" by "replacement 2" (in the replace_df) and so on (as in the script example below)

```
in_list<-lapply(files_in_list, readLines)
 out_list<-list() 
  for (i in 1:length(in_list)) {
      out_list[i]<-gsub(replace_df[i,1],replace_df[i,2],in_list[i])
}
```

Although a little dirty, it works fine. The problem I have is writing these files to .txt files. When I try to writeLines, it results in messy files, with every line in quotes and losing the format of the original file. How to avoid that the result files do not contain quotes in each line, keeping the original format?
Greetings

Comment: I can't reproduce. `writeLines(c("hello", "world"), "test.txt")` produces a file with no quotes in it. Can you provide a little bit of sample input that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Not sure if this might be related, but when assigning to a single list item you should use `[[`, that is `out_list[[i]]<-gsub...`

Comment: Oh yes, it was a typo (out_list[[i]]...). The input is a list of txt files, typical configuration files of a given program, for example:
###this parameter configures one thing##
parameter1=1
###this parameter sets something else###
parameter2=0.5

and so, for each file in the list, change parameter1

Comment: in the output, each line is enclosed by quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `in_list[i]` with `in_list[[i]]`, for the same reason that @GregorThomas suggested it for `out_list`.

As a demonstration:

```r
in_list <- list(c('a','b'), c('a','b'))
gsub('a', 'A', in_list[1])
# [1] "c(\"A\", \"b\")"            # wrong

gsub('a', 'A', in_list[[1]])
# [1] "A" "b"                      # correct
```

Comment: Oh, yeah! What a silly mistake!!, thanks a lot to @GregorThomas and you